# Ты и туда(,) и обратно с велосипедом поедешь?

Tags: запятые

Нужна запятая?

> Привет. Ты и туда(,) и обратно с велосипедом поедешь?

Comment: При двух однородных членах предложения, соединенных повторяющимся союзом «и», запятая не ставится, если образуется тесное смысловое единство: https://popravilam.com/blog/063-soyuz-i-povtoryaetsya-no-zapyataya-ne-nuzhna.html. Тут смысловое единство недостаточное по сравнению с "ты и лето и зиму носишь одну и ту же куртку", поэтому запятую не ставим.

Comment: @user190920 "Тут смысловое единство недостаточное... поэтому запятую не ставим". Противоречиво как-то...

Comment: А ну да, опечатался, ставим то бишь.